# Use a radio input to make a div visible with CSS

Tags: css, input, radio-button, visible

I would like to use a radio input to make a div visible when it's selected.
Here's what I've got but it doesn't work.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="menu" id="btn_commandprompt" value="1"></input>
                <label for="btn_commandprompt"">
                    <div id="btn_commandprompt_design"></div>
                </label>

<div id="commandprompt"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #commandprompt{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}


#btn_commandprompt:checked ~ #commandprompt{
    display: block;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It works for me: https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/JLeoON
 Which browser are you using? Or you are looking for a particular case?

Comment: yes your code works. my answer is another alternative.

Comment: You're right O_o it works here: https://codepen.io/brochard/pen/xWQbQL but it doesn't work in my project: https://codepen.io/brochard/pen/VXVYgd Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have modify your code. its now working...


  <style>
   #commandprompt{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}


#btn_commandprompt:checked ~ #commandprompt{
    display: block;
}
  </style>

<body>
<input type="radio" name="menu" id="btn_commandprompt" value="1"> Show Me</input>
<input type="radio" name="menu" id="btn_acceuil" value="1"> Hide Me</input>

<div id="btn_commandprompt_design"></div>

<div id="commandprompt">ooh!!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Now I have to find out why it doesn't work in my projet ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
this should work


<body>
<input type="radio" name="menu" id="btn_commandprompt" value="1" onclick="show()"> Click Me</input>
<div id="btn_commandprompt_design"></div>

<div id="commandprompt" style="display:none">Show Me</div>
</body>


<script>


function show(){
  document.getElementById("commandprompt").style.display = 'block';
}


</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I would like to do it with CSS and I use a radio input so when I choose an other answer I want the div to disapear, someone helped me to make it work here  https://codepen.io/brochard/pen/xWQbQL but it doesn't work in my project https://codepen.io/brochard/pen/VXVYgd if you can help me find out why it would be great :)

Comment: It's up for me, I tried without being connected it works, try reloading the page. (edit: you missed a letter at the end of the URL)

Comment: Ok check it out . just added another answer. Please kindly upvote the answer if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok check it out . just added another answer. Please kindly upvote the answer if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It would work if you put something inside the Div. Your code is correct, just add a paragraph inside your Div for example and try it again.